# How can I remove the extra padding from my longtable's right-most column?

Tags: longtable

I used the following code to create a longtable with five columns that stretches the full width of the page. I like everything about this table except for the fact that *all* columns are padded to make the table as wide as the page. Instead, I would like the first four columns to expand in this way, but I would like the fifth column (the one with header D) to be "sized to content". That is, I would like it to be only as wide as it needs to be to fit its values.

```
\documentclass[table]{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[left=0.50in,top=2.0in,right=0.50in,bottom=1.0in]{geometry}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{pdflscape}

\begin{document}

\setlength\LTleft{0pt}
\setlength\LTright{0pt}
\begin{longtable}{l @{\extracolsep{\fill}} |   r|r|r|r}

        \multicolumn{5}{r}{\bfseries {\Large{My Table}}} \\

       & {\bfseries A}
       & {\bfseries B}
       & {\bfseries C}
       & {\bfseries D}
       \\
       \endfirsthead

        \multicolumn{5}{r}{\bfseries {\Large{My Table (continued)}}} \\

           % name
       & {\bfseries A}
       & {\bfseries B}
       & {\bfseries C}
       & {\bfseries D}
       \\
       \hline
       \endhead

            \hline

               \hspace{4mm}\ Row 1 \hspace{2mm}
            & 1,200
            & 800
            & 2,000
            & 1
            \\

               \hspace{4mm}\ Row 2  \hspace{2mm}
            & 1,201
            & 801
            & 2,001
            & 123
            \\

\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

How it currently looks:

[image]

My crude approximation of how it should look:

[image]

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: As always on the site, please provide a full minimal example, not sniplets. With a full but minimal self contained example it is a lot easier for others to copy your code and test it as is. Here we have to add  stuff to even compile it, so a lot of people will not even bother to look at it.

Comment: I have updated the code to show the full document, rather than just a snippet. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[hmargin=0.50in,top=2.0in,bottom=1.0in]{geometry}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\usepackage{array, longtable}
%\usepackage{pdflscape}

\begin{document}

%\setlength\LTleft{0pt}
%\setlength\LTright{0pt}
\begin{longtable}{@{\qquad}l| *{3}{>{\raggedleft}p{0.25\linewidth}|} r}

        \multicolumn{5}{r}{\bfseries {\Large{My Table}}} \\

       & {\bfseries A}
       & {\bfseries B}
       & {\bfseries C}
       & {\bfseries D}
       \\
       \endfirsthead

        \multicolumn{5}{r}{\bfseries {\Large{My Table (continued)}}} \\

           % name
       & {\bfseries A}
       & {\bfseries B}
       & {\bfseries C}
       & {\bfseries D}
       \\
       \hline
       \endhead

            \hline

Row 1       & 1,200
            & 800
            & 2,000
            & 1
            \\

Row 2       & 1,201
            & 801
            & 2,001
            & 123
            \\

\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Works great, thank you!